# how to set up icinga2 on Debian

Tags: icinga2

The biggest problem is that CLI wizard doesn't work on Debian package. So  `icinga2 node wizard` is impossible.

So i have to edit configs manually, but this is so weird, that after reading i know less then before.

Few questions:

1. what is a difference between satelitte and client?
2. What is a difference between zone and cluster?
3. If set zones and endpoints, should I see hosts on webpanel? Or I have to set it independently?

I want to see all my hosts in one web panel, and I want to manage it from this one master computer.

I think, that I have to run icinga2 on all hosts.

What I did for now:

On master computer I changed zones.conf:

```
/*
 * Endpoint and Zone configuration for a cluster setup
 * This local example requires `NodeName` defined in
 * constants.conf.
 */

object Endpoint "chart-left" {
  host = "127.0.0.1"
}
object Endpoint "gonzales" {
  host = "W.X.Y.Z"
}

object Zone "master" {
  endpoints = [ "chart-left" ]
}

object Zone "checker" {
  endpoints = [ "gonzales" ]
  parent = "master"
}
/*
 * Defines a global zone containing templates,
 * etc. synced to all nodes, if they accept
 * configuration. All remote nodes need
 * this zone configured too.
 */

/*
object Zone "global-templates" {
  global = true
}
*/
```

And on client computer zones.conf differs with IP:

```
/*
 * Endpoint and Zone configuration for a cluster setup
 * This local example requires `NodeName` defined in
 * constants.conf.
 */


object Endpoint "chart-left" {
  host = "A.B.C.D"
}

object Zone "master" {
  endpoints = [ "chart-left" ]
}

object Endpoint "gonzales" {
  host = "127.0.0.1"
}
object Zone ZoneName {
  endpoints = [ "gonzales" ]
  parent = "master"
}
/*
 * Defines a global zone containing templates,
 * etc. synced to all nodes, if they accept
 * configuration. All remote nodes need
 * this zone configured too.
 */

/*
object Zone "global-templates" {
  global = true
}
*/
```

And in both logs appears some informations:

master:

```
[2016-04-13 00:47:17 +0200] information/ApiClient: Reconnecting to API endpoint 'gonzales' via host 'W.X.Y.Z' and port 5665
```

client:

```
[2016-04-13 00:54:10 +0200] information/ApiListener: New client connection for identity 'chart-left'
```

But looking at panel I still see only localhost (chart-left) - which is defined in hosts.conf.

The zones.d tree looks like:

```
zones.d/
  README
  checker/
  global-templates/
  master/
```

without any files in checker/ master/ nor global-templates/

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question, but does solve the problem of the CLI not working properly. You can install the packages from debmon (this version is a bit newer) following the [Icinga2 Getting Started Guide](http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/toc#!/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/getting-started#package-repositories). (Make sure that you actually install the new version rather than the one in jessie.) Then you can just use the wizards.

Comment: Did it, but still not happy with it ;D Why debian package is "broken"?